# SAS dynamic library names

Tags: sas

I am trying to figure out how to create a dynamic library reference. I have figured out how to create directories, but now: how to create library references properly?

The code below works, but it required a repeat of the code. The first block does not create a reference, but the second one does. Putting the same into a loop (to execute lines twice) does not work...

I would like to redo this code into a macro, so that the root directory would be assigned when calling the macro.

Thanks in advance!

```
data _null_;
rootdir='c:/temp';
dir1=put(today(),yymmddn8.);
dir2='Individual';
dir3='Household'; 
newdir1=dcreate(dir1,rootdir);
newdir2=dcreate(dir2,newdir1); 
newdir3=dcreate(dir3,newdir1);
lname=catx('/',rootdir,dir1,dir2);
lname2=catx('/',rootdir,dir1,dir3);
call symput('ln1',lname);
call symput('ln2',lname2);
libname Indiv "&ln1";
libname HH "&ln2";
run;

data _null_;
rootdir='c:/temp';
dir1=put(today(),yymmddn8.);
dir2='Individual';
dir3='Household'; 
lname=catx('/',rootdir,dir1,dir2);
lname2=catx('/',rootdir,dir1,dir3);
call symput('ln1',lname);
call symput('ln2',lname2);
libname Indiv "&ln1";
libname HH "&ln2";
run;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
%macro libs(rootdir);
data _null_;
dir1=put(today(),yymmddn8.);
dir2='Individual';
dir3='Household'; 
newdir1=dcreate(dir1,&rootdir);
newdir2=dcreate(dir2,newdir1); 
newdir3=dcreate(dir3,newdir1);
call symput('ln1',catx('/',&rootdir,dir1,dir2));
call symput('ln2',catx('/',&rootdir,dir1,dir3));
run;
libname Indiv "&ln1";
libname HH "&ln2";
%mend libs;

%libs("c:/temp")
```

Seems to do the trick. Not sure if the most efficient way of doing it, but at least it is a way. Thank you Joe for the suggestions that led me to the final answer.

Comment: You should be able to do all of that by wrapping things in %sysfunc and skipping the data _null_ step.  But in the scheme of things it probably doesn't matter.  Certainly the CALL SYMPUT should be doable via let; if it's not working right for you then it's probably an issue with quoting that you'd want to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

libname does not need to be executed in the datastep; it's an open code statement.  So your code can simply run the datastep and then afterwards run a libname statement, ie

```
data _null_;
rootdir='c:/temp';
dir1=put(today(),yymmddn8.);
dir2='Individual';
dir3='Household'; 
newdir1=dcreate(dir1,rootdir);
newdir2=dcreate(dir2,newdir1); 
newdir3=dcreate(dir3,newdir1);
lname=catx('/',rootdir,dir1,dir2);
lname2=catx('/',rootdir,dir1,dir3);
call symput('ln1',lname);
call symput('ln2',lname2);
run;
libname Indiv "&ln1";
libname HH "&ln2";
```

Really though no data step is needed for any of this...

```
%let dir1=%sysfunc(today(),YYMMDDN8.);
%let dir2=Individual;
%let dir3=Household;
%let ln1=c:/temp/&dir1./&dir2.;
%let ln2=c:/temp/&dir1./&dir3.;
x "md &ln1.";
x "md &ln2.";
libname Indiv "&ln1.";
libname HH "&ln2.";
```

You don't even have to create ln1 and ln2, you can directly assign the libname to the text that would be ln1 and ln2.  I added the directory creation statement as well to make it clear how that would interact (and if you do use that, you should use the intermediate ln1/ln2).

Comment: Thank you. One question: 
What does `x "md &ln1.";` do?

Comment: That executes the system command 'md' (make directory) with your directory name.  You had mentioned creating directories, so this is how I'd do it (on a desktop Windows machine - on a server or unix/linux/etc., it would be at least somewhat different).

Comment: It generates an error in SAS (at least under Windows)... And it has to work on PC and Unix

Comment: Doesn't cause an error for me, but like I said it depends on your setup.  If you're running off EG or something, you might be restricted from using 'x'; if it's giving you a SAS error (as opposed to a windows complaint about the directory not existing or something) it's very possible you don't have permission to run x commands.  Either way if you have a different way that works for that part, use that :)

Comment: The error is a DOS error: "incorrect syntax". However, as mentioned, I'd like something platform independent, and I definitely need it to be UNIX compatible. 
The second code is not working even without x statements...
The first suggestion works though. Now, how do I make it into a macro function of rootdir?

Comment: Not sure what you mean about a macro function of rootdir.  You mean add in &rootdir. ?  Just replace C:/temp with &rootdir./ and have an extra %let... `%let rootdir=c:/temp;` and then `%let ln1=&rootdir./%dir1./&dir2.;` etc.

Comment: If you're getting a DOS error, it might be either because you are using / instead of \ (SAS will correct for that in the LIBNAME but perhaps not in the X command), or because you have/need quotes or something in the directory name if you're not using the exact directory you posted.

Comment: In Unix, use 'md' to create the directory. In Windows, use 'mkdir' to create it. You could use the system macro variable SYSSCP to determine which host system you're running on, and set the command and path delimiter (e.g. / or \\) accordingly.